# Ajax for Rails 3 : onchange

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, onchange

The below code renders the *.js.erb file and updates the display div when hit on the Display button. but it doesn't render the *.js.erb file onchange of the dropdown, it only renders the *.html.erb. 
any idea?

```
<%= form_tag monitors_path, :id => 'monitor',:method => :get, :remote => true do %>
    <%= collection_select(:monitor, :job_id, Job.all, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "Select a Run"}, {:onchange => "$('monitor').submit()"} ) %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Display' %>
<% end %>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Thanks,
Volkan

Comment: What does the controller action code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked but not sure if it's the best solution for rail 3.

```
{:onchange => remote_function(:method => :get, :url => {:action => 'index'}, :with => 'Form.Element.serialize(this)')}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** From [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/):

Change `$('monitor').submit()` to `$(this).parents('form:first').submit();`.

Running out of ideas. :)

---

2nd (bad) answer:

**Edit:** Actually, shouldn't it be `$('#monitor')` instead of `$('monitor')`?

---

Previous (bad) answer:

Try this: in `{:onchange => "$('monitor').submit()"}` add `; return false` after `submit()`.

Comment: I'm just riffing here; I don't currently have a test environment to try it on.  Just trying to come up with the solution off the top of my head, sorry if nothing good comes out of it.

Comment: thanks, i appreciate it. nope it's $('monitor'). it's weird that the submit button delivers the ajax call but not the onchange submit :\

Comment: "$(this).parents" is not a function says my firebug.

Comment: i'm using rails 3. i'm still not clear whether remote_function is deprecated or not from rails 3. i don't know how to send ajax get with onchange submit.

Comment: @Volkan: The article I linked in my answer is for Rails 3, and it uses the jQuery library; don't you?  If you do use jQuery, then I suggest you try reading through the article and find what you're doing wrong, if anything.